How to configure multiple DNS settings for different network services on macOS?
I have one network cable connected to my Mac, and I've set up two services in the Network settings:

Internet Realtek LAN
IP: 192.168.1.1 | DNS: 192.168.1.1 or 1.1.1.1 (either works for me)

Labo Realtek LAN
IP: 192.168.137.1 | DNS: 192.168.137.1


When I ping the server or access it via IP using curl or a browser, everything works fine. However, I need both DNS settings to work simultaneously. From what I've observed, macOS uses the DNS of the service listed first in the service order under Network settings. This means only one DNS is active at a time.
Is this correct? If so, how can I configure macOS to use both DNS settings as needed? Any solutions or workarounds would be appreciated.





That's not really how DNS works.  If you query a server, and get NXDOMAIN, it's not going to round-robin to the next server and ask again.  You would need to run a single server that could respond for both networks, and probably forward queries it didn't recognize vs responding with NXDOMAIN.

I finally found a way to have two networks, one LAN and one VLAN. See my configuration below:

Internet Realtek LAN

IP: 192.168.1.1
DNS: 192.168.1.1 or 1.1.1.1


Labo Realtek LAN

IP: 192.168.137.1
DNS: 192.168.137.1



The order is quite important Setting > Network > ... > Set Service Order....

The trick was to add the DNS of the VLAN 192.168.137.1 before 1.1.1.1.

And also put it here.

